# What is the spread between maturities called?

Tags: terminology, spreads, yield-curve

Credit spreads typically compare two bonds of the same maturity. For example, a 10-year US Treasury yielding 3% might be compared to a Corporate Bond yielding 4.5% and we'd say the spread was 1.5%.

However, when people talk about inverted yield curves predicting recessions they talk about comparisons like the US10Y-US2Y yield spread.

Is it accurate to call a comparison of yields between to different maturities a spread? And if so, what's the proper way to distinguish a spread that doesn't match maturities to a spread the more typical spread that does match maturities? Does the difference as to which type of spread one is talking about infer one is speaking about different risks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is accurate to call a comparison between different maturities a spread. Formally you would refer to the spreads between similar issues in different maturities as the curve spread, so the "two-year ten-year US Treasury curve spread"

Informally though, if you said the "2's 10's Treasury spread" a Trader would know what you're referencing. I trade on the US Dollar swap curve and we say the "2's 10's swap spread" all the time.

I wouldn't say the default interpretation of a spread is necessarily one that matches maturities. A "spread" is just a difference between two observable values or prices, the prefix gives the spread reference it's meaning. **curve** spread, **credit** spread, **basis** spread etc.